# How to swap objects in an array in mongo db

Tags: mongodb

Here is my array, How to swap an index in an array in mongodb, here is my parents array having 3 objects i need to change the zeroth index object to second index object and second index to zeroth index like that  (every time i will pass index which has to changed and where to be)

```
{
"message": "student data",
"data": {
    "_id": "5f30c5bfdc2ccd147982b768",
    "adm_no": "abc6",
    "parents": [
        {
            "_id": "5f30c5bfdc2ccd147982b769",
            "relationship": "5f27b39b7745232279add4f6",
            "user_id": "5f30c35c2fd97b1265f8d409",
            "parent_id": "5f30c35d2fd97b1265f8d40d"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f30fae95ba82a295aacfe11",
            "relationship": "5f27b39b7745232279add4f6",
            "user_id": "5f30fae85ba82a295aacfe0e",
            "parent_id": "5f30fae95ba82a295aacfe0f"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f3125110440821cf7d6b813",
            "relationship": "5f27b39b7745232279add4f6",
            "user_id": "5f30fae85ba82a295aacfe0e",
            "parent_id": "5f30fae95ba82a295aacfe0f"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

I tried with positioning in mongodb but i am getting some string casting error.
please help me on this Thank You

Comment: Why do you need to swap items?

Comment: I am configured zeroth index to primary contact person. so when ever i am changing primary contact person i want to update that object to zeroth index. 
that we can also acheive by taking another field `is_primary` make true false, while in this process every time  i need to iterate parents array on frotned and fetch primary contact details so that is the reason i asked for swapping